# Php simple calculator

Tags: php, isset

i am a beginner in php ,i am trying to do a calculator but something is wrong .i don´t know what is it .when i click the butoon submit the fields turn empty .

```
<head>
<title>Funcion isset()</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form name="forma" method="post">
        Realitza una operacio: <br> <br/>
        <input type="text" name="num1"> </t> Operador 1 <br /></br/>
        <input type="text" name="num2"> </t> Operador 2 <br /></br>
        Operació:</br></br>
            <input type="radio" name="opcion" value="+">Suma  <br /></br/>
            <input type="radio" name="opcion" value="-">Resta <br /></br/>
            <input type="radio" name="opcion" value="*">Multiplicacio <br /></br/>
            <input type="radio" name="opcion" value="/">Divisio <br /></br/>
            <input type="radio" name="opcion" value="p">Potencia <br /></br/>
            <input type="submit" name "submit" value="Calcular">
    </form>
<?php
        if (isset($_POST['calcular']))
              { 
                $n1 = $_POST['numero1'];
                $n2 = $_POST['numero2'];
                $oper = $_POST['opcion'];
                 switch ($oper) {
                    case "+":echo  $n1 + $n2;break;
                    case "-": echo $n1 - $n2; break;
                    case "*": echo $n1 * $n2;break;
                    case "/":echo $n1 / $n2;break;
                    case "p": echo pow( $n1,$n2);break;
               }
              }     
?>
</body>
</html>
```

any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

There are two obvious problems here:

1. Instead of `<input type="submit" name "submit" value="Calcular">` you have to fix the syntax: `name="submit"`
2. And you have to check for a post variable with name "submit": `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`

In general, to debug such problem is is always the first check to really look what values you are actually working with. In this case this means: what is actually continaed in `$_POST`? So the first step would be to dump that array using `var_dump($_POST);` or similar.

Comment: Thank you very much !the probleme was there on submit ,as you said .and i had to change   $n1 = $_POST['numero1'];
                $n2 = $_POST['numero2']; with   $n1 = $_POST['num1'];
                $n2 = $_POST['num2']; regards from Spain :)